# Problem with plotting multiple semilog plots using \foreach

Tags: pgfplots, plot, loops, foreach

I want to plot multiple plots using \foreach with 2 variable inputs, one to pass the changing parameter and the other to pass the color of the plot. My MWE is as follows.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,intersections}
    \newcommand{\V}{\widetilde{V}}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{color}
     \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[axis line style={->,thick},every tick/.style={color=gray},smooth,,xlabel={$\V$ /(\si{\cm \tothe{3}\per\mole})},ylabel={$P$ /bar}, xmin=10,xmax=1e5,ymin=-100,ymax=200,clip=false]
    \def\m{9.864*10^7}%a
    \def\R{8.314}
    \def\n{45.05}%b
    \foreach \y/\c in {200/red,275/blue,300/green,304/red} {
        \addplot[color=\c,domain=50:1e5] {(\R*\y)/(x-\n) - \m/(\y^0.5*x*(x+\n))};
    \addlegendentry{$T$ = \y \si{\kelvin}}}
```

Compilation just gives either error of undefined control sequnce or the plot that does shows up does not have any points. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to make a MWE (minimal (non-)working examle). -remove `\newcommand`, `\def`, `\addlegendentry` -add `\end{document}`. Try with a simpler function. How much is the exponent in `y^0.5*x*(x+\n)`?. You need something that is compilable, and then make it more and more into what you want -then you will know what goes wrong.

Comment: I will keep that in mind - thanks for the heads up. I tried making the function less complex but I don't think it was the complexity that was the problem, it was the color option of \addplot. It doesn't accept a loop variable as an input. @Torbjørn T.  answered my question. The trick is to define a custom cycle list for passing different colors to the color option of \addplot.

Comment: @scorpionwars *A* trick a least, not necessarily *the* trick. And I don't think it's exactly that `\addplot` doesn't allow for the use of a loop variable in the options, but that loops inside `axis` environments are a bit more tricky in general because many macros are only evaluated at the end of the environment, *after* the loop. There is some discussion about this in chapter 8 of the `pgfplots` manual, have a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant using a custom `cycle list` and `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` instead of `\foreach`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{MyColors}{
  red,thick\\
  blue,thick\\
  green,thick\\
  cyan,thick\\
 }
\newcommand{\V}{\widetilde{V}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
    axis line style={->,thick},
    every tick/.style={color=gray},
    smooth,
    xlabel={$\V$ /(\si{\cm \tothe{3}\per\mole})},
    ylabel={$P$ /bar},
    xmin=10,xmax=1e5,
    ymin=-1200,ymax=200, %changed ylim
    cycle list name={MyColors},% use the cycle list defined above
    legend style={legend pos=south east}]
\def\m{9.864*10^7}%a
\def\R{8.314}
\def\n{45.05}%b
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{200,275,300,304} {
    \addplot +[domain=50:1e5] {(\R*#1)/(x-\n) - \m/(#1^0.5*x*(x+\n))};
    \addlegendentry{$T = \SI{#1}{\kelvin}$} % <-- note that this has changed
} 
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Addendum

For using a single color that gets lighter, you can use `opacity` with a small calculation, e.g.

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{200,210,...,300} {
    \addplot [domain=50:1e5,color=blue,very thick,opacity=(#1-180)/300] {(\R*#1)/(x-\n) - \m/(#1^0.5*x*(x+\n))};
    \addlegendentry{$T = \SI{#1}{\kelvin}$} 
}
```

What numbers you use depend entirely on the values of the loop variable, you want numbers that are between 0 and 1 as the result. For this case you don't need the `cycle list` of course.

## Addendum 2

Or you can use the `blue!<number>!white` feature to make the color go from light blue to blue using the code

```
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {200,210,...,300} {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rat}{(\i-180)/1.2}
    \edef\temp{\noexpand
        \addplot [domain=50:1e5,color=blue!\rat!white,very thick]
            {(\R*\i)/(x-\n) - \m/(\i^0.5*x*(x+\n))};
                \noexpand\addlegendentry{$T = \SI{\i}{\kelvin}$}
    }\temp
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Torbjørn! That's exactly what I was looking for. Just as a small follow up, is it still possible to change the color option using a loop. Let's say I had 20-30 parameters and I wanted to plot this function with a color that is progressively getting lighter as T decreases, is there a way that color option will accept a parameter from \pgfplotsinvokeforeach command.

Comment: @scorpionwars For that specific case there is a fairly easy way, see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: I would not use `opacity` to make the color lighter but change the white part of the color like `blue!100` to `blue!10` or similar.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I agree, and I did try that, but I couldn't get the calculation working in the loop. Could be I did something wrong though.

Comment: May I edit your answer to show how this is done? For a comment it will be a bit "clumsy" to write and adding another answer is also not needed I think.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Please do, if you don't want to add another answer.